# Check Engine light comes on every time I return from Griffith obs

Tags: honda, civic, hybrid

Honda Civic Hybrid 2004.  Check Engine light comes on every time I return from Griffith Obs.  Every month I have an evening meeting.  I park facing downhill, so when I go home I turn on the car and coast the 2-3 miles to a major road.  By The time I get to that road the check engine light is on. One time I took it to Honda and they said it was the O2 sensor.

This happens 100% of the time (for the last 7 months) I make that trip.  It is the only time the light comes on.  It always goes off within 2-3 days.  What do you think would cause an O2 sensor to trigger under these conditions?

Comment: Have you had the codes read for the vehicle? If so, what are the exact codes?

Comment: What is the elevation difference between your home and the Observatory?

Comment: @mikes from 1130 ft (Griffith) to 550 ft (Los Feliz/Hillhurst) is only 580 ft drop in 1.6 miles of driving.

Comment: @RobertFarley ... The exact code would help tremendously.